# file/directory access control for multiple users across network

Tags: permissions, nfs, acl

I have the following setup:
LDAP Server for users/groups
Several Ubuntu computing servers
NFS Server running on Ubuntu Server shared across all computing servers
NFS Server running on Synology NAS shared across all computing servers

I want:

- Allow users to share data they own on the NFS with other users
- Deny specific users access to some folders stored on the network storage (these could be owned by a system user)

Problem:
There are different ACLs used for local filesystems, NFS & synology, that are not compliant with each other.

Question:

- Is there a way to set ACLs in a central database and enforce Ubuntu to authenticate any read/write/execute request of a user against that ACL database instead of its own permission management?